# obtain :title field in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, response

I'd like to store page titles in some place for later use. I used nifty-generators to generate layout.

How to access value, which was set by title() method in view? I need to catch it in controller. Is it stored somewhere in response?

or do I need to move title setting to controller action, as I wonder if what I want to do is possible from mvc nature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use any variable in more than one request then you should keep it in controller. There are many ways to do this like:

1. You can pass this variable in URL.
2. keep it in the session
3. keep it in the cookie
4. In rails you can also use flash.now